# Spatial interpolation with Copula

Tags: python, interpolation, spatial, spatial-interpolation

I was wondering if anyone knows about a library for spatial interpolation using Copulas in Python. I have already tried the `copulalib` and consequently `ambhas`, but none of them are suited for spatial interpolation. A reference to the problem can be found [here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.332.9877&rep=rep1&type=pdf).

Regards,